# using widgets instead of activeform in yii2

Tags: yii2, widget

I a new yii2 developer. I want to use widgets instead of activeForms. However, i do not know how to do it. Please, give me hint how to use widgets.
In my file, I have following code:

```
<div class="">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'title_ru')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'description_ru')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'content_ru')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'type')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'region')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'category')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'status')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'image')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'title_en')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'title_uz')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'title_uzk')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'description_en')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'description_uz')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'description_uzk')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'content_en')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'content_uz')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'content_uzk')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

//learning widgets

Comment: what you have tried so far??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually ActiveForm is a widget you can see for yourself by `use` keyword in top of your php view file

it will be something like

```
<?php

use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
```

---

but if you want to use other widgets make it like this (use `->widget()`) instead of `textInput` or `textarea`

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>



<?= $form->field($model, 'company_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Companies::find()->all(), 'company_id', 'company_name'),
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a category ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
]); ?>
```

make sure you put your own data.

You can find a lot of widgets here http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-widgets/